# How to setup Windows 7 per device Autoplay?

Tags: windows-7, windows, autoplay

Autoplay works, but the devices are not listed in Control Panel - AutoPlay - Devices, thus I can't set it up per device. Tried two different PCs, USB sticks, USB harddisk, DVDs, nothing. In XP I could just right-click the disk and there was Autoplay tab.

Comment: When you are going to `Control Panel - AutoPlay - Devices` do you have one of the devices plugged in?  They won't display there if not currently attached.